# How to solve can't getById?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-8, nuxtjs3, pinia

i'm trying to write a test to test that the method that gets categoryById returns the correct data but i'm getting Null. please does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue? thanks

***My CategoryController***

```
public function show($id)
    {
        try {
            $category = Category::find($id);
            return response()->json([
                'success' => 'OK',
                "categories" => $category,
            ], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 400);
        }
    }
```

***My vue store***

```
        async getCategoriesById(id) {
            let res = await $axios.get(`/api/categories/${id}`)

            // this.$state.id = res.data[0].id   <-- this is also not working
            
            console.log(res)
        },
    },
```

***My Categories Component***

```
onMounted(async () => {
  getCategoriesById()
})

const getCategoriesById = async () => {
  try {
    await $forumStore.getCategoriesById(route.params.id)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)

  }
}
```

***My route***

```
Route::get('/categories/{id}', [CategoryController::class, 'show']);
```

***My issue***

[image]

Comment: First off, figure out your casing; you have `$category`, which is a good name for a single `Category` model, but you then return it as `'categories'`, which suggests multiple... Why? And `getCategoriesById`, should be `getCategoryById`. Your code looks ok, but what is `$id`? Make sure you have a record in the database with the matching `id`, i.e. `/api/categories/1` should find a record with an `id` of `1`.

Comment: onMounted(async () => {
  getCategoriesById()
})

Here the problem is that the method was not called properly and the id was not passed to it

Comment: @mohammedalbadry `getCategoriesById()` calls `$forumStore.getCategoriesById(route.params.id)`, which _is_ passing the `id` via `route.params.id`

Comment: Perhaps `route.params.id` is empty then. Try to console.log that or return $id from the controller to see if the `id` is even being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id is passed to the controller correctly make sure you actually have a category with the given id sitting in your database. Category::find($id) just returns null if there is no category with the matching id in the database. So, the result is correct as you're returning a successful response without handling a null result. Use Category::findOrFail($id) instead if you want to trigger an error when no category is found.